# Elasticsearch Get Index Mapping from a File

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am looking a way of having index mapping in a file so that it should be loaded when the elasticsearch is starting. Elstic documentation explains how to get so that using a rest call. I know that index mapping template can be use to set a mapping before creating the index.
Anyone can help me how to read the index mappings from a file?

I will store the mapping details in a text file and then I want to upload the file to the elastic search.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried and what's the issue you are facing in that approach?

Comment: I wanted to read a text file from logstash pipeline. Still I don't have a clue how to proceed?

Comment: So you want a text file being read in by logstash and used as the payload for a index mapping request in elasticsearch? Where the index name will come from?

Answer (score -1):

if you write your own filters for any index you need to create a mapping template.
logstash has many dynamic options so can map many fields by default.

but please ask your question more clear. what do you mean by reading from file ?
in kibana console you can see the mappings for any index.

1. open kibana
2. go to development tools
3. type in console : GET /index/_mapping

for example if you wanna see all indices for logstash pattern , type : **GET /logstash-*/_mapping**

**note** : you can see the full mapping template like : **GET /_template/logstash**

note : for loading your template to elasticsearch type :**curl -XPUT -H 'Content-Type:application/json' http://localhost:9200/_template/test -d@test.template.json**

which "test" is your template name and "test.template.json" is your file.

hope this helps and rate if that helped. thanks

Comment: what I am talking about is, I will store the mapping details in a text file and then I want to upload it to the elastic search